# script wont restart after Authentification failed

Tags: linux, shell

I wrote this script for an openconnect vpn connection. Now i want to check if the output which is stored in $vpn contains "Authentication failed". If it contains then it should exec. the script again.

My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Bitte Passwort eingeben:
read x
if [ -z "$x" ]
then
    echo "Kein Passwort eingegeben!!!"
        echo "Bitte erneut versuchen"
            exec "/home/ubuntu/Dokumente/vpn.sh"
else
        vpn=$(echo $x |
        sudo openconnect vpn.domain.de --user=test.vpn --passwd-on-stdin --authgroup vpn-client-no-ise --no-dtls)
fi
if [[ $vpn == *"Authentication failed"* ]]; then
  echo "Dein Passwort war falsch!"
    exec "/home/ubuntu/Dokumente/vpn.sh"
fi
read
```

When i type a wrong password, it just shows "Authentication failed". But it does not restart the script as expected.
And the second thing is, when i type the correct password, it also do not connect.
When i remove this part:

```
if [[ $vpn == *"Authentication failed"* ]]; then
  echo "Dein Passwort war falsch!"
    exec "/home/ubuntu/Dokumente/vpn.sh"
fi
```

the connection with the correct password works. But i want to restart the script if the $vpn contain "Authentication failed".
Maybe someone can see my mistake.

**Update:
Ok, what i now figured out is that the "Authentification failed" message is not in the $vpn. It is every time outside the variable. 
But i don't understandt why, because the $vpn() goes around the command and the message should be also inside the variable.
Or do I have to put it another way to receive answers also into the variable?**

Comment: Have you considered using a loop?

Comment: I was thinking about that. How do you think is the best way to write it in my case?

Comment: 1. A [while loop](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/While_loop) would seem convenient. 2. Are you sure the `Authentication failed` is coming from `openconnect` and not from `sudo`? `openconnect` should say all kinds of things about the connection to the vpn server being established etc.

Comment: I wrote a while loop and saw that the authentification failed status is not in the openconnect answer. It has to be in the sudo. Command. How can I read from sudo? Haven't done this before.